# Extract token after particular substring in bash

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a string variable in a bash script that contained several lines:

```
blah blah blah
...
...
an interesting parameter: 12345 some other useless stuff...
...
...
```

I want to extract 12345 from this string. I have tried to look for ways to use 'an interesting parameter:' as a "delimeter" but I couldn't quite get it to work. Is there a clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bash` supports regular expression matching without using external programs.

```
$ str='
blah blah blah
...
...
an interesting parameter: 12345 some other useless stuff...
...
...'
$ [[ $str =~ an\ interesting\ parameter:\ ([[:digit:]]+) ]]

$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
12345
```

The array `BASH_REMATCH` contains the full match in element 0 and the captured subgroups (in left-to-right order) in subsequent elements.

Comment: Definitely better than an external program! +1

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
grep -Po 'an interesting parameter:\s*\K\S*'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this `sed` command,

```
sed -n '/interesting parameter/ s/.*parameter: \([0-9]\+\) .*/\1/p' file
```

For your case it would be,

```
sed -n '/interesting parameter/ s/.*parameter: \([0-9]\+\) .*/\1/p' <<< "$string"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use sed:

```
sed -n 's/.*an interesting parameter: \([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p' <<< "$string"
```

Answer (score 3):

Pure Bash using regex:

```
$ a='blah blah blah
> ...
> ...
> an interesting parameter: 12345 some other useless stuff...
> ...
> ...'
$ [[ $a =~  "an interesting parameter: "([[:digit:]]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
12345
```

Pure Bash using parameter expansions:

```
$ t=${a#*an interesting parameter: }
$ echo "$t"
12345 some other useless stuff...
...
...
$ u=${t%% *}
$ echo "$u"
12345
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`cat content | grep "an interesting parameter: " | awk '{print $4}'`