# grep/sed/awk a specific word from a table

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting, grep

The list looks like something this:

```
9      vm_mail                        running
11     vm_webserver                   running
13     vm_proxy                       running
15     vm_wsus                        running
```

Now i only need the vm name in the middle while only using "vm" as searchterm
any ideas?

Comment: You need only the four `vm_*` "words" from that example?

Comment: So what is the expected output, all of those lines? Anything in particular that you're stuck with?

Comment: let's say `grep vm | cut -f2` to grep any line containing vm and printing only the second field. (if all lines contant a vm name, just use `cut -f2 inputfile` as it seems the input is tab separated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract token after particular substring in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810833/extract-token-after-particular-substring-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -Po '(?<=vm_)\S*'
```

gives you:

```
mail
webserver
proxy
wsus
```

Comment: that would be exactly what i need thank you :)

Comment: The leading `.*` is redundant, though.

Comment: @tripleee you are right. fixed